# Hit-Testing and Resolving Occlusion of AutoShapes in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, hittest

I am using code to draw a number of AutoShapes in Excel based on user input using VBA. However, some of these shapes may occlude each other, so I would like to run a second pass to hit-test which shapes occlude and to nudge them until they no longer occlude.

So the basic pseudocode outline would be:

```
do
    foreach shape s in shapes
        if (s.hittest(shapes)) then
            do
                s.nudgeup(1)
            until (!s.hittest(shapes))
        endif
    next
until (!shapes.hittest(shapes))
```

Can any of you think of some way of doing this (or even working around this so this doesn't have to be done)?

I've taken a look at the RangeFrom function, but that doesn't seem to be much use (only returns *one* shape at a specific screen coordinate, not intersecting shapes).

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not build the placement of these shapes into the code that initially draws them?

Comment: does the below work for you? if so, you can select the hollow checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the below:

```
Sub MoveShapes()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet
    Dim s1 As Shape
    Dim s2 As Shape

    For i = 1 To sh.Shapes.Count
        If i < sh.Shapes.Count Then
            Set s1 = sh.Shapes(i)
            Set s2 = sh.Shapes(i + 1)
            If s2.Left < (s1.Left + s1.Width) Then
                s2.Left = (s1.Left + s1.Width + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This code would need more work however to account for top/bottom and multiple overlaps, but this should be enough to get you start.