# Determining if AutoShapes overlap/occlude in Excel and moving vertically to resolve

Tags: vba, excel

I am using some VBA code to create an autoshape and a text box, group them, and move to a vertical and horizontal position based on cell positions.

The code will look at user input to create and group the shape & textbox, and will usually create over 100 shapes, many of which will overlap.  Currently, the groups are placed with reference to the top of a row;  I want to separate them so that they don't overlap.

I would like to be able to determine if a group overlaps another group, and if so, to move it down 25pts.  Given that this check would need to then determine if the new position also overlaps, it's becoming a bit too complicated for my skill level (self-taught beginner.)

I have researched this extensively, and I've come across the following VBA code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet
Dim s1 As Shape
Dim s2 As Shape     Dim CheckOverlap As Boolean

For i = 1 To 10 'sh.Shapes.Count
If i <= sh.Shapes.Count Then
        Set s1 = sh.Shapes(i)
        CheckOverlap = False
        For Each s2 In Worksheets("Plan").Shapes
                    If s2.Left < (s1.Left + s1.Width) And s2.Top < (s1.Top + s1.Height) Then
                        CheckOverlap = True
                        Exit For
                    End If

        Next
    If CheckOverlap = True Then
        s2.Top = s2.Top + 30
        End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I found the basis of the code here:

[Hit-Testing and Resolving Occlusion of AutoShapes in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158128/hit-testing-and-resolving-occlusion-of-autoshapes-in-excel/5162025#5162025)

However, I haven't been able to figure it out how to make it check whether overlap occurs vertically as well as horizontally, as well as the multiple-overlap problem.  Currently, if I execute that code, it just moves every shape down even irrespective of whether it overlaps.

If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it!  This is the hardest part of my project and I'd love to find a solution.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: When you insert the shapes initially, why don't you specify their positioning so that they do not overlap? Should be able to do this using the .Top and .Left properties.

Comment: Hi DyRuss - I do the .Left position against column (to show the relevant date) and the .Top position against the target audience.

The document shows 6 months and plots communications events against target audience and date.  We often expand or contract the view to show a month or week in more detail. The data that creates and positions the shapes often changes, so that it's not feasible to specify for individual shapes where they're placed relative to other shapes - I need to just move them vertically once they're otherwise in place, and I expand the row height for particular cells if needed

Comment: Ok I think I have a solution. Do you want the charts next to one another horizontally (like on an x axis) or vertically(y axis). Are all the charts about the same size?

Comment: All shapes are 23 pts high and wide. I want them to be adjacent vertically - ie. the only movement should be moving down, **not** horizontally.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. This should align all the charts on the active sheet vertically 25 points apart

```
Sub MoveShapes()
   Dim IncrementTop, TopPosition, LeftPosition, i as Long
   IncrementTop = 0
   LeftPosition = 'place the desired starting left position here
   TopPosition = 'place the desired starting top position here
   For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
      ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Left = LeftPosition
      ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Top = TopPosition + IncrementTop
      IncrementTop = IncrementTop + 25
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm looking for - I don't want to space them evenly as a general rule, I want to only space if they physically overlap.  I've edited my code above to show what I'm trying at the moment.  If it helps I can send you an example of what I want it to do so you can get a better idea.  thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer:

```
Sub MoveShapes1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet
Dim s1 As Shape
Dim s2 As Shape
Dim CheckOverlap As Boolean

For i = 1 To sh.Shapes.Count
If i <= sh.Shapes.Count Then
        Set s1 = sh.Shapes(i)
Search:
    CheckOverlap = False
    For Each s2 In Worksheets("Plan").Shapes
        If s2.ID = s1.ID Then GoTo Suit
        If s2.Left <= (s1.Left + s1.Width) And s2.Left >= s1.Left _
        And s2.Top <= (s1.Top + s1.Height) And s2.Top >= s1.Top Then
            s1.Top = s1.Top + 32
            CheckOverlap = True
            Exit For
        End If
Suit:
        Next
    If CheckOverlap = True Then GoTo Search
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```